# How to implement a Laplace filter in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I implemented my own Laplace filter but it does not look like the Laplace filter in Gimp for example. What is wrong?

My attempt
[image]

Gimp
[image]

```
cv::Mat ImageManipulation::mylaplace_filter(cv::Mat image){
    int laplace_mask[9] = {0, -1, 0, -1, 4, -1, 0, -1, 0};
    int tmp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    cv::Mat laplaceImage = cv::Mat::ones(image.rows-2,image.cols-2,CV_8U);
    for(int i = 1; i<image.rows-1; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<image.cols-1; j++){

            for(int k = i-1; k<i+2; k++){
                for(int l = j-1; l<j+2; l++){
                    tmp += laplace_mask[counter] * static_cast<int>(image.at<uchar>(k,l));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            std::cout << tmp/9 << std::endl;
            laplaceImage.at<uchar>(i-1,j-1) = tmp/9;
            tmp = 0;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return laplaceImage;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what Gimp does there, but that is also not a correct output for a Laplace filter. Negative values are important, you can't throw them out by saturating to zero. You need to create a signed output image, and store the signed result. Also, your normalization of 1/9 is odd. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the type of the image "laplaceImage", before getting into the loop, and as @Cris Luengo commented, no need to dividing by 9:

```
cv::Mat ImageManipulation::mylaplace_filter(cv::Mat image)
{
    int laplace_mask[9] = { 0, -1, 0, -1, 4, -1, 0, -1, 0 };
    int tmp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    cv::Mat laplaceImage = cv::Mat::ones(image.rows - 2, image.cols - 2, CV_32F);

    for (int i = 1; i < image.rows - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < image.cols - 1; j++)
        {

            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; l++)
                {
                    tmp += laplace_mask[counter] * static_cast<int>(image.at<uchar>(k, l));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
            laplaceImage.at<float>(i - 1, j - 1) = tmp;
            tmp = 0;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return laplaceImage;
}
```

after that if you want to show "laplaceImage" or save it on hard disk, you can adjust it between 0 and 255, then convert it to CV_8U.

Comment: What is the reason for the normalization by 9? Never seen that before.

Comment: sorry my fault I took it from the mean filter, I implemented before. It is not necessary

Comment: You need to scale the image for display. The `int32` image potentially has values in the range [-255*8, 255*8]. You could do `laplaceImage/16+128` to display it properly. Or find the actual min and max values in the image. But this is a display issue, not something that should be mixed into the computation of the filtered image.

Comment: You need to add `@Cris` to notify me when you replay to my comment, otherwise I only see your comment by chance. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple code, this will helps to understand basics

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Mat src_gray, dst;

    Mat src = imread("ball.jpg");
    int kernel = 3;
    Mat filter = (Mat_ <double>(3,3) << 1,1,1,1,-8,1,1,1,1); // Laplace Filter

    filter2D(src, dst, -1, filter);
    imshow("Simple Function", dst);
    imshow("Simple Source", src);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Making your own linear filters!**
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dbd/tutorial_filter_2d.html

**Laplace Operator**
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html