# How to implement Laplace filter using the kernel's absolute value?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Laplace filter by using convolution and the kernel's absolute value. The problem is, the image I get after running the function is not what it should be. Can you please point out what do I miss or what should I do differently?

I'm using OpenCV and C++ and trying to run on a greyscale image.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void convulutionCalc(Mat imgOut, Mat imgIn, Mat kernel,int radius) {

    for (int i = 0; i < imgIn.rows - (2 * radius); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgIn.cols - (2 * radius); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2 * radius + 1; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 2 * radius + 1; l++) {
                    imgOut.at<unsigned char>(i + radius, j + radius) += (imgIn.at<unsigned char>(i + k, j + l) * kernel.at<double>(k, l));
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{@input | lena.jpg | input image}");
    Mat src = imread(samples::findFile(parser.get<String>("@input")), IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat gsrc;
    cvtColor(src, gsrc, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    if (src.empty())
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 4.0 / 4.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0);

    Mat laplaceImg = gsrc.clone();
    convulutionCalc(laplaceImg, gsrc, kernel, 1); //image out, image in, kernel, kernel radius

    imshow("Lalpace", laplaceImg);
    waitKey();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The image I get looks like this:

[image]

Even if I'm trying with a different kernel the result is not what it should be, so I think thats's not the problem.

Comment: Why develop your own convolution methods , why not just use OpenCV's filter2D? And your filter kernel looks nothing like a Laplace filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a Laplace filter in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763711/how-to-implement-a-laplace-filter-in-c)

Comment: Because our professor want us to "know exactly" how this filter works so we have to implement it.

Comment: I also tried with this kernel:  
`Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 4.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);`

Comment: What was the result? There could still be a bug in your convolution routine but that looks like a better kernel.

Comment: https://ibb.co/mJTXtGm 
The left picture is the result after using the kernel above, the other one is from the question you suggested.

Comment: You cannot use an 8-bit unsigned integer to accumulate the intermediate result of the filter. Accumulate into a double (the two inner loops), then scale and offset the result as necessary before writing into the output image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The main issue is that you are not scaling the output of the convolution. Remember that the output of the convolution is just the sum of the element-wise product of the input image and the kernel. So, if your kernel is all ones, then the output will just be the sum of all the pixels in the input image.

To fix this, you need to scale the output by the sum of the kernel values. In your case, the sum of the kernel values is 1/4 + 1/4 + 4/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 2. So, you just need to divide the output of the convolution by 2.

Here is my version:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void convolutionCalc(Mat& imgOut, Mat& imgIn, Mat& kernel, int radius)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imgIn.rows - (2 * radius); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgIn.cols - (2 * radius); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2 * radius + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 2 * radius + 1; l++)
                {
                    imgOut.at<unsigned char>(i + radius, j + radius) += (imgIn.at<unsigned char>(i + k, j + l) * kernel.at<double>(k, l));
                }
            }
            // scale the output by the sum of the kernel values
            imgOut.at<unsigned char>(i + radius, j + radius) /= (4.0 + 1.0 + 4.0 + 1.0);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{@input | lena.jpg | input image}");
    Mat src = imread(samples::findFile(parser.get<String>("@input")), IMREAD_COLOR);
    Mat gsrc;
    cvtColor(src, gsrc, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    if (src.empty())
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 4.0 / 4.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 4.0, 0.0);

    Mat laplaceImg = gsrc.clone();
    convolutionCalc(laplaceImg, gsrc, kernel, 1); // image out, image in, kernel, kernel radius

    imshow("Laplacian", laplaceImg);
    waitKey();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```